# pandas.read_excel from active sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlwings

I'm trying to run python code from excel with xlwings. In my code I'm using pandas to read from the excel and put the data into a dataframe. The function `pandas.read_excel(io, sheet_name=0, nrows=0, usecols=0)` reads from excel. So my `sheet_name` is my current sheet('Sheet3'), my `nrows=3` and `usecols="A:F"`. I've problems with the `io`. `io` is the excelworkbook I want to use: `'workbook1.xlsm'`. When I'm running the code from vs code, all works fine, but when I run it from excel as a macro

```
Sub test()
    RunPython ("import test")
End Sub
```

I get the error: `file not found`

What could be the reasons?

Comment: Post the full traceback, not merely 3 words from the exception.

Comment: To fix your problem, I suspect you either need to set `io` to the absolute filepath (e.g. `r"C:\Users\Savelimeister\Desktop\workbook1.xlsm"` or change the current working directory to the directory where `workbook1.xlsm` is saved, by calling `os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Savelimeister\Desktop")`, for example, before your call to `pandas.read_excel()`.